# SimpleAdminConfig и autodiscover()

Tags: django

Есть необходимость сделать админку Django на другом урле, при этом сохранив автоматический импорт всех моделей из `admin.py` других приложений, то есть функцию `autodiscover()`

В [документации](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/contrib/admin/index.html#multiple-admin-sites-in-the-same-urlconf) описано такое решение, но ничего не сказано касательно того, как для одного из экземпляров `AdminSite` сохранить возможность автоматического импорта.

Нужно, чтобы:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls), # здесь импортировались как и всегда, при помощи autodiscover()
    url(r'^myadmin/', admin_site.urls), # здесь импортировались те, которые я зарегистрировал 
]
```

Comment: Не нужно писать в заголовке, что это вопрос о чём-то там. Вместо этого кратко сформулируйте сам вопрос.

Comment: Это как на коробке написать «коробка», сообщение не содержащее информации.